# Java stream collect arrays into one list

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to use the new stream functionality to expand a list of strings into a longer list.

```
segments = segments.stream() //segments is a List<String>
    .map(x -> x.split("-"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This, however, yields a `List<String[]>()`, which of course won't compile. How do I reduce the final stream into one list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-):

```
segments = segments.stream() //segments is a List<String>
    .map(x -> x.split("-"))
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also remove intermediate array using [`Pattern.splitAsStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#splitAsStream-java.lang.CharSequence-):

```
segments = segments.stream() //segments is a List<String>
    .flatMap(Pattern.compile("-")::splitAsStream)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `flatMap`:

```
segments = segments.stream() //segments is a List<String>
    .map(x -> x.split("-"))
    .flatMap(Stream::of)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that `Stream.of(T... values)` simply calls `Arrays.stream(T[] array)`, so this code is equivalent to @TagirValeev's first solution.